# parsing nested XML nodes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nested

Hello I am trying get all the possible nested hierarchy key value of following XML.

I want to create HTML for each node_name with some content and i want hierarchy menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <taxonomies>
      <taxonomy>
        <taxonomy_name>World</taxonomy_name>
            <node atlas_node_id = "355064" ethyl_content_object_id="82534" geo_id = "355064">
               <node_name>Africa</node_name>
        <node atlas_node_id = "355611" ethyl_content_object_id="3210" geo_id = "355611">
            <node_name>South Africa</node_name>
            <node atlas_node_id = "355612" ethyl_content_object_id="35474" geo_id = "355612">
                <node_name>Cape Town</node_name>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355613" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355613">
                    <node_name>Table Mountain National Park</node_name>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node atlas_node_id = "355614" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355614">
                <node_name>Free State</node_name>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355615" ethyl_content_object_id="1000550692" geo_id = "355615">
                    <node_name>Bloemfontein</node_name>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node atlas_node_id = "355616" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355616">
                <node_name>Gauteng</node_name>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355617" ethyl_content_object_id="37710" geo_id = "355617">
                    <node_name>Johannesburg</node_name>
                </node>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355618" ethyl_content_object_id="1000548256" geo_id = "355618">
                    <node_name>Pretoria</node_name>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node atlas_node_id = "355619" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355619">
                <node_name>KwaZulu-Natal</node_name>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355620" ethyl_content_object_id="43725" geo_id = "355620">
                    <node_name>Durban</node_name>
                </node>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355621" ethyl_content_object_id="1000576780" geo_id = "355621">
                    <node_name>Pietermaritzburg</node_name>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node atlas_node_id = "355622" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355622">
                <node_name>Mpumalanga</node_name>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355623" ethyl_content_object_id="67561" geo_id = "355623">
                    <node_name>Kruger National Park</node_name>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node atlas_node_id = "355624" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355624">
                <node_name>The Drakensberg</node_name>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355625" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355625">
                    <node_name>Royal Natal National Park</node_name>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node atlas_node_id = "355626" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355626">
                <node_name>The Garden Route</node_name>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355627" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355627">
                    <node_name>Oudtshoorn</node_name>
                </node>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355628" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355628">
                    <node_name>Tsitsikamma Coastal National Park</node_name>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
        <node atlas_node_id = "355629" ethyl_content_object_id="3263" geo_id = "355629">
            <node_name>Sudan</node_name>
            <node atlas_node_id = "355630" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355630">
                <node_name>Eastern Sudan</node_name>
                <node atlas_node_id = "355631" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355631">
                    <node_name>Port Sudan</node_name>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node atlas_node_id = "355632" ethyl_content_object_id="" geo_id = "355632">
                <node_name>Khartoum</node_name>
            </node>
        </node>
        <node atlas_node_id = "355633" ethyl_content_object_id="3272" geo_id = "355633">
            <node_name>Swaziland</node_name>
        </node>
    </node>
</taxonomy>
```

Here what i tried:

```
@block = doc.xpath("taxonomies/taxonomy/node/node")
@chld_name = @block.map do |node|
  node.children.map{|n| [n.name,n.text.strip] if n.elem? }.compact
end.compact
#p @chld_name

def parse(element)
  children = element.children.reject{|e| e.is_a?(Nokogiri::XML::Text) && e.text =~ /^\s*$/}
 if children.count == 1 && children[0].is_a?(Nokogiri::XML::Text)
 children[0].text
 #p children
  else
    data = Hash.new
    children.each do |child|
    #p child
     data[child.name] = parse(child)
   end
 data
 end
  end

  campaigns = doc.xpath('/taxonomies/taxonomy/node/node').map{ |c|
    parse(c)
  }

  p campaigns
```

How can i do this? i tried many codes but no luck :(

Comment: Welcome to SO! “i tried many codes but no luck” does not work here. Please show us your attempt and where you got stuck.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thank you for your response here is my code below.